# How to use Apache Camel correctly for specific scenario?

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel, internal

**Problem Overview**

I'm using apache camel 2.4 and have been asked to setup an internal messaging system in one of our maven/spring projects. This may seem a little weird but its because they have plans to separate some functionality out at a later date and want the integration side already covered.

**Desired Functionality**

Basically I have a bean (A) that does some processing and creates a serializable object. I have another bean (B) that accepts said serializable object and does some additional processing that we want to occur asynchronously.

The plan is to have bean (A) produce a message via the SEDA component of Camel and have it consumed by bean (B) internally.

**What I've Done**

So far I have implemented this by;

-Creating a RouteBuilder implementation that defines the route.

-Configuring my CamelContext in spring to use said route builder.

-Creating a "producer" class that has the CamelContext as a property and uses this to create a ProducerTemplate with which to send the message. - used by bean (A).

-Defining bean (B) as the consumer (via "bean:beanB" in the configured RouteBuilder).

**Question**

This works but, being new to Camel, i'm not sure if this is a very good way of implementing the desired functionality. Having looked further at the Camel docs its seems like there's lots of different ways I could do the same thing (configuring the route in spring, rather than defining a RouteBuiler implementation, using the SedaEndpoint implementation, defining the ProducerTemplate in spring and using this as a dependency rather than the CamelContext itself.....).

What would be standard practice / best method for implementing the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wire things together various ways, but what you have described is pretty standard...

that said, you might consider the following...

- don't create a new ProducerTemplate for each invocation of your producer (reuse it, etc.)
- be aware of the expected messaging rates of the producer/consumer and possibly enable multi-threaded consumption using [camel-seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) concurrentConsumers property
- use a newer version of Camel than 2.4 (currently at 2.10.2)